# Doctrine ODM / PHP / MongoDB - ReferenceOne ID changed or nulled when flushed

Tags: php, mongodb, doctrine-orm, doctrine-odm

I'm trying to do a simple ReferenceOne with MongoDB/Doctrine, but I
get a really weird problem:

```
My ID:4e63611cbc347053a2000001
Create the Privilege Object
Check what's the Privilege->User Id
4e63611cbc347053a2000001
Persist it
Create the Event Object
Persist it
Check what's the Event->Privilege->User Id
4e63611cbc347053a2000001/OK/0
Flush it
Get my document id
4e6546d6bc34700605000012
Check what's the Event->Privilege->User Id
4e6546d6bc34700605000013/NOK/0
```

As you can see here, I create a Privilege Object where I reference a
User, I persist it => all ok. No I create a Event Object, I embed the
Privilege in it, check the id => all ok.

Now I flush it, and the user->id gets changed, I have no idea why this
happens.

I tried removing the cascade to see how it behaves and I just end up
with a null $id.

Any help would be welcome to understand what I'm doing wrong!

Here is the code I use:

```
echo "My ID:".$identity->getId()."<br />";
echo "Create the Privilege Object<br />";
$privilege = new \Entity\ODM\Event\Privilege();
$privilege->setUser($identity);
$privilege->setRole("admin");
echo "Check what's the Privilege->User Id<br />";
echo $privilege->getUser()->getId()."<br />";

echo "Persist it<br />";
$dm->persist($privilege);

echo "Create the Event Object<br />";
$event = new \Entity\ODM\Event();
$event->setName("My Event 222");
$event->setDate("25/08/2012");
$event->setUrl("myevent222");
$event->addPrivilege($privilege);
echo "Persist it<br />";
$dm->persist($event);

echo "Check what's the Event->Privilege->User Id<br />";
   $privs = $event->getPrivileges();

$output = $identity->getId();
$i = 0;
foreach($privs as $priv)
{
    if($priv->getUser()->getId() == '4e63611cbc347053a2000001')
        $output .= "/OK/".$i."<br />";
    else
        $output .= "/NOK/".$i."<br />";
    $i++;
    echo $output;
}

echo "Flush it<br />";
$dm->flush();
echo "Get my document id<br/>";
$id = $event->getId();
echo $id."<br/>";

$privs = null;
$priv = null;
echo "Check what's the Event->Privilege->User Id<br />";
   $privs = $event->getPrivileges();

$output = $identity->getId();
$i = 0;
foreach($privs as $priv)
{
    if($priv->getUser()->getId() == '4e63611cbc347053a2000001')
        $output .= "/OK/".$i."<br />";
    else
        $output .= "/NOK/".$i."<br />";
    $i++;
    echo $output;
}
```

Trimmed Entities:

```
class Event {
    /**
     * @Id
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @EmbedMany(targetDocument="\Entity\ODM\Event\Privilege")
     */
    protected $privileges = array();
}

class Privilege {

/**
* @Id
*/
protected $id;

    /**
     * @ReferenceOne(targetDocument="\Entity\ODM\User",
cascade={"persist"})
     */
    protected $user;

/**
 * @param field_type $user
 */
public function setUser(\Entity\ODM\User $user) {
    $this->user = $user;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason the code here works perfectly fine under symfony2.

The problem is coming from the way I implemented doctrine in Zend (modified Bisna) - Closing this question.